# Error = Device orientations are not supported in Mac Catalyst processes?

Tags: ipados

**Error = Device orientations are not supported in Mac Catalyst processes**

Got this error when selecting the Destination = "My Mac (designed for iPad".

I tried using the following Code Snippet in my GameViewController, but it did not work. Can anyone provide some guidance?:

```
#if os(iOS) && !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    
    // for rotation Landscape <-> Portrait = iOS,
    // but *not* for Mac (built for iPad)
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        showScene()
        
    }   // viewDidLayoutSubviews

#endif
```

Comment: What’s an ‘Error = Device’ orientation?

Answer (score 0):

A very, very interesting observation:

In my iPad Computer Game already uploaded to the App Store, I don't have any code that calls:

`targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)`

Yet, when in the distant past, this previous iPad Game of mine became available for download from the App Store, just on a whim, I downloaded it to my iMac Desktop to see what would happen. It worked with Ventura and Sonoma.  ASAMOF, in its Supported Destinations, I just had iPad with **zero** mention of `Mac (Designed for iPad)`.

SO, I eliminated any testing for `targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)` in the above **#if** and set the Product's Destination to **My Mac (Designed for iPad)**

AND IT WORKED!

Bottom Line = apparently I don't need to test for **targetEnvironment**.

Anyway, sorry to bother you folks with what turned out to be a very simple correction.